# Speed up thread pool growth in CLR

Tags: .net, task, clr, threadpool

Our application creates many tasks, that run on CLR thread pool.
Number of tasks may be from 10 to 10 thousands.

When number of tasks quickly increases then many tasks fail to complete in given time.

That is because thread pool adds only one new thread per second (though there may be hundreds of waiting tasks).

The following test demonstrates the problem:

```
[Test]
public void TestTasks()
{
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10000, 10000);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1);
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        int ci = i;
        Task.Run(() => {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + $" {ci} - START");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // long operation simulatation
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + $" {ci} - FINISH");
        }, source.Token);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    source.Cancel();
}
```

The typical output is

```
01:38:37.171 0 - START
01:38:37.171 1 - START
01:38:37.172 2 - START
01:38:37.172 3 - START
01:38:38.029 4 - START
01:38:39.029 5 - START
01:38:40.030 6 - START
01:38:41.031 7 - START
01:38:42.029 8 - START
01:38:42.172 0 - FINISH
01:38:42.172 9 - START
01:38:42.173 3 - FINISH
01:38:42.173 1 - FINISH
01:38:42.173 2 - FINISH
01:38:42.173 10 - START
01:38:42.173 11 - START
01:38:42.173 12 - START
01:38:43.029 13 - START
01:38:43.030 4 - FINISH
01:38:43.030 14 - START
01:38:44.030 5 - FINISH
01:38:44.030 15 - START
01:38:44.030 16 - START
01:38:45.029 17 - START
01:38:45.031 6 - FINISH
```

**Is there any way to increase speed of thread pool growth?**

**Update 1.**
The above example shows the main problem: tasks are created by new modern library which uses async/await style code. But most of tasks are old legacy code with thread-blocking operations. The application works. And at constant low or constant high load it shows good performance. Performance problem begins when number of tasks is rapidly increasing: although there are thousands waiting tasks, but CPU utilization stays low.

**What is the most easy way to cope with the described situation?**

Comment: No, it is fixed at half a second.  It is only meant as a countermeasure against TP threads that take too long to get their job done, it is not meant to create thread explosions.  Sets the "too long" measure as well, half a second.  That's an easy ~4 billion cpu instructions on a modern processor, unless you calculate the value of pi you'd only get there by excessive I/O delays.  To which the universal solution is async code, the kind that doesn't need a TP thread to wait for the I/O operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thread pool does not know that the tasks use async/await style code or thread-blocking code.
Therefore, it cannot change its thread management strategy.

If you have a lot of old-style legacy thread-blocking code then just increase minimum number of threads in thread pool.